# Hohmann transfer trajectory and "porkchop plot"

Tags: hohmann-transfer

The “porkchop plot” for a spacecraft flying from Earth to Mars would show contours of equal characteristic energy against combinations of launch date and arrival date. Assuming the spacecraft has sufficient performance margin, could it “step up” to another contour at a later point in the mission by changing its Hohmann transfer trajectory so it arrives at Mars sooner than originally planned?

Comment: It could alter its transfer trajectory to arrive sooner, but it would be less efficient than having done it from the start (and wouldn't be a Hohmann).